# rubygems.rb cannot be loaded

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

On Linux Mint 17.3, I upgraded from Ruby 1.9.2 to Ruby 2.3.0 using RVM, and now the 'gem' CLI and every Ruby program that uses gems are returning the following error:

`<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in`'`

I have tried reinstalling Ruby, switching to other versions (including back to 1.9.2), reinstalling RVM, and `rvm fix-permissions`, none of which have changed the error.

Any idea what's going on here?

EDIT: I was able to get CLI functionality back seemingly by repeatedly reinstalling 2.3.0 (`rvm reinstall` rather than uninstalling and reinstalling manually). However, programs that require gems are still breaking with the same error.

Comment: How did you do the upgrade? Also 1.9.2 is a super arcane version of Ruby so it's a good thing you're trying to update it. First thing to check: What does `which gem` say?

Comment: I just installed it and then used `rvm use 2.3.0`. `which gem` returns `/home/[username]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/gem`

Answer (score 1):

The below might help:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

If nothing helps, try to manually remove 1) all rubies from RVM and 2) rvm directory:

```
rm -rf /home/[username]/.rvm
```

and reinstall RVM from the scratch.

Comment: This could be a [catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)) if you can't get `gem` to fire up in the first place.

Comment: @tadman right, but I recall I had a similar issue and `gem` was still runnable.

Comment: RVM is usually pretty good about bundling the right `gem` with the release, but if it malfunctions super badly you might be stuck. Here's hoping this works, though!

Comment: I was able to run these (see my edit to the original post) but unfortunately I'm still having the issue with programs that require gems.